# Need Shell Script to find difference in two files based on first column

Tags: shell, scripting

I have two files and each file is having two columns

`File1` having below columns:

```
ECDLT 5  
DBG0  0  
AHDST 53  
RSNDL 10  
DBLOG 2  
ATDLM 1  
ATREJ 1  
DLMKT 0   
AKDRP -100  
ALTCM 100000000    
BCPTM -1000000000   
PERFS 1  
OMSTD 1  
LDTHD 1  
DGCAN 1  
HRLOG 1  
AKALT 0
```

`File2` having below columns:

```
ECDLT 5  
DBG0  0  
MFLOR 1  
LIPEM 1  
GXTHR 5  
LIPEM 1  
LIPEM 1  
RPTAT -1  
RPTPA -1  
PTIMR 1  
NOQUE 1  
AHDST 53  
RSNDL 10  
DBLOG 2
```

So, here i need a shell script to find difference in two files using first column and in the output it should print both columns.

I am new to shell scripting. Please help me in this. I am in very bad need.

Comment: I am not sure what you are asking, can you either give more details in what you want the output to look like, or give an example output?

Comment: If you observe the first column in each file, few rows are having different value..So i need the difference value of two files (should compare the files using only first column)

Answer (score 5):

(edited to make this more concise. Move direction from the script to the commandline so you have more control on where you want the output)

Based on the description that you only want to print the first two columns from file1, and only the lines where the 1st column values are different against the corresponding rows in the 2nd file (and assuming first file has more lines than the 2nd file):

```
#!/bin/bash

paste $1 $2 | awk '{if ($1 != $3) {print $1 " " $2}}'
```

and this is how it would use the script (name it diff_col.sh):

```
$ chmod +x diff_col.sh
$ ./diff_col.sh input_file1 input_file2 > output_file
```

with your sample input, and just

```
$ ./diff_col.sh input_file1 input_file2
```

I get:

```
AHDST 53
RSNDL 10
DBLOG 2
ATDLM 1
ATREJ 1
DLMKT 0
AKDRP -100
ALTCM 100000000
BCPTM -1000000000
PERFS 1
OMSTD 1
LDTHD 1
DGCAN 1
HRLOG 1
AKALT 0
```

Comment: yes..i am looking for the output like this..

but i am confused..where we are doing diff & how?

Comment: You don't need diff. The comparison is done inside the awk script (http://www.grymoire.com/Unix/Awk.html)

Comment: okay..i understood..but its printing the first two columns of both files..(i need it should print first two columns of file1)

Comment: Use the updated script. It is printing the first two columns of file1 (see the example output in the answer)

Comment: its simply printing two columns from file..but its not doing diff with first column from second file..

Comment: I don't understand what you are looking for. Provide more details such as a complete expected output given input files.

Comment: see for example "AHDST 53 " is present in two file and its printing in output. So in my case it should not print the same values in two files.